# Filemaker value list - default value for each layout

Tags: filemaker

I have a question regarding value lists in Filemaker. I have a value list called "eventtype" inside, I have 3 values. Now, those values are being shown in a field "eventtype". But due to the nature of my app, I need to separate those 3 events and make a layout for each of them. I would like to have the field "event type" fulfilled upon entering the Card layout for each of those 3 events. For example, I would like to report an alarm, upon entering the "CARD new alarm" I would like to have the value of "event type" already fulfilled with the value "Alarm". Same goes for other 2 event types and their respective layouts. Now, can this be done ? Or should I separate those values and create new fields in my table ? - But that would complicate things, since I need to show all of those events on my main layout under a field "event type". Can that field then show the data from other 3 fields ?

sorry if this is too long, let me know if I can explain it better.

Comment: At some point (not  clear from your question) you need to identify the event type you wish to report. At that point two things should happen: (1) the EventType field should be populated and (2) you should be taken to the corresponding layout. How you want to present the choice is largely a matter of user interface. For example, you could have three buttons, one for each type. Or you could select from a drop-down/pop-up/radio-button and have a triggered script take you to the selected type's layout. Those are just 2 examples, there are other options.

Comment: Ah yes, on my main layout I have a button that says "new event" and it's a popover button from which you get 3 choices, each for one of the specified events. Clicking on the button takes you on the event specific layout. Meaning I could make it work that as soon as I click on the popover button the field gets populated with the data right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the simplest solution is to place three buttons in your popover, each calling the same script with a different parameter.

Then your script would be something like:

```
If [ Get (ScriptParameter) = "Alarm"]
  New Window [ Style: Card; Using layout: “CARD new alarm” ]  
  New Record
  Set Field [ Events::EventType; "Alarm" ]
Else If [  Get (ScriptParameter) = "Foo"  
  New Window [ Style: Card; Using layout: “CARD new foo” ]  
  New Record
  Set Field [ Events::EventType; "Foo" ]
Else If [  Get (ScriptParameter) = "Bar"  
  New Window [ Style: Card; Using layout: “CARD new bar” ]  
  New Record
  Set Field [ Events::EventType; "Bar" ]
End If
```

---

Or perhaps more succinctly:

```
If [ Get (ScriptParameter) = "Alarm"]
  New Window [ Style: Card; Using layout: “CARD new alarm” ]  
Else If [  Get (ScriptParameter) = "Foo"  
  New Window [ Style: Card; Using layout: “CARD new foo” ]  
Else If [  Get (ScriptParameter) = "Bar"  
  New Window [ Style: Card; Using layout: “CARD new bar” ]  
End If
New Record
Set Field [ Events::EventType; Get (ScriptParameter) ]
```